# Maxima is adding an unnecessary %i in taylor series

Tags: sympy, maxima, wxmaxima

I'm using Maxima 5.44. In the taylor expansion of a radical, Maxima introduce an unnecessary imaginary unit.

I'm trying the following calculation:

`rr:sqrt(1-a*cos(θ)^2);`
`taylor(rr, θ, 0, 2);`

The result is:

`sqrt(a-1)*%i-(sqrt(a-1)*%i*a*θ^2)/(2*a-2)+...`

Even though it's correct the imaginary unit is annoying as everything will be computed in the real line.
I would have preferred:

`sqrt(1-a)-(sqrt(1-a)*a*θ^2)/(2*a-2)+...`

as it will be shorter and more clear.
Is there a way to force maxima not to insert the imaginary unit?
I tried with `assume(a<1)` but it didn't work.
For example sympy don't introduce this additional imaginary unit.

This is part to a larger calculation, of course.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you try to fake a one with "`1`:" (or whatever the syntax is, exactly). Then perhaps it will not try to extract a minus sign in rewriting `1 - a` as `a - 1`.

Comment: That was '1': where ' is replaced with backquote mark to create the symbol with name "1".

Comment: The observed behavior is a consequence of Maxima's pretty strong idea about ordering terms in "+" expressions (and maybe other things). I'm not entirely sure where `sqrt(1-a)` is getting turned around to `%i*sqrt(a - 1)`, but anyway I find I can subvert it by introducing another variable which sorts after `a`; I find `b` has the expected behavior. I.e. write `sqrt(b - a*cos(θ)^2)` and substitute 1 for `b` afterwards. I'll try to look at this again later today.

Comment: It's not working. I mean it's working for that simple expression, but not for a more complicated. I'm trying to find the expansion of a quite complicated function as function of theta and I'm expecting that all the terms up to the fourth power to be zero. But that problem create fake terms for theta less then 5. When I tried to use another variable instead of 1, sometimes it worked (in the same expression), some times no and I got a %i. That meant that even if I use rectform to make %i disappear some terms got a -1 and don't cancels.

Comment: Okay, sorry to hear it's not working. I will try to investigate the %i question. In the meantime, I think it would probably help if you post the whole problem you are working on; that will make it easier for others to know whether some proposal or the other is moving towards a solution.

Comment: Edmondo, something else that could possibly help. Try the function `rootscontract` on the expression which contains `sqrt(...)*%i`. In some cases it will absorb `%i` into `sqrt`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution I have found so far. (I recognize that even this is imperfect.) Credit to Barton Willis for this.

```
(%i1) block([taylor_simplifier : rootscontract], taylor (sqrt (1 - a*cos(θ)^2), θ, 0, 2));
                                             2
                          (sqrt(- a + 1) a) θ
(%o1)/T/  sqrt(- a + 1) - -------------------- + . . .
                                2 a - 2
```

EDIT: Another way I found, via the flag `radexpand`.

```
(%i1) radexpand: false $

(%i2) taylor (sqrt (1 - a*cos(x)), x, 0, 2);
                                             2
                          (sqrt(- a + 1) a) x
(%o2)/T/  sqrt(- a + 1) - -------------------- + . . .
                                4 a - 4
(%i3)
```